# Get image from scanner in web app

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, flash

I need to build a web application in asp.net where users can use their scanner to upload images to the website. Is there a flash or a silverlight component out there that can accomplish this?

Comment: Dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956158/wia-through-web-browser-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Flash or Silverlight might not a good choice. You may use an ActiveX (in IE) or an NPAPI plugin (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) to get access to the scanner via the TWAIN API.

If you have the time or a limited budget, you can create your own plugin. Otherwise, you can try a commercial TWAIN library. Dynamsoft has a multi-browser web-scanning toolkit which supports scanning and uploading images in all mainstream browsers/

Disclaimer: I work for Dynamsoft.